# coldfusion cfimport IIS unstable execution

Tags: iis, coldfusion, cfimport

I have created customtags (7 files, nested tags) using CF9 and call it using cfimport, when I run it on my notebook with CF9 dev edition with built in CF web server, it run with no problem, but when I run on IIS it sometime it's show blank page or partial execution only (never completely run)

error stack trace:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
 at coldfusion.excel.Excel.createNewWorkbook(Excel.java:118)
 at coldfusion.excel.Excel.<init>(Excel.java:86)
 at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.SpreadSheetNew(CFPage.java:6779)
 at cfsheet2ecfm424522201.runPage(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\tscf\spreadsheet\sheet.cfm:73)
 at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
 at coldfusion.filter.CFVariablesScopeFilter.invoke(CFVariablesScopeFilter.java:56)
 at coldfusion.tagext.lang.ModuleTag.doStartTag(ModuleTag.java:271)
 at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
 at cfexcel2ecfm1846306446.runPage(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\tscf\excel.cfm:19)
 at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
 at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
 at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
 at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:342)
 at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
 at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
 at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:87)
 at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
 at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
 at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
 at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
 at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
 at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
 at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
 at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
 at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
 at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
 at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
 at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
 at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
 at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
 at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
 at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
 at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
 at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
 at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
 at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
 at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
 at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

noted: **java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError**
it happened when I use SpreadsheetNew() function even when only call it by simple SpreadsheetObj = SpreadsheetNew()

```
env 1:
CF9 dev edition
win 7 professional
built in cf web server
java 1.6.0_16
```

env 2:
CF9 enterprise
win 2003
IIS 6
java 1.6.0_20

thank you

Comment: Can you give a description of what is working on the IIS 6 box?

Comment: Hi jarofclay, 
I added error stack trace (cferror error.stacktrace). error.diagnostic "null null <br>The error occurred on line 73"

Comment: maybe you need OpenOffice installed?

Comment: Hi Henry, 
env 1, yes, it has OpenOffice, but I uninstall it and try to run the script, and the spreadsheet object created. then I try to reinstall CF9 without OpenOffice, and the spreadsheet object created too. I think it's not about the OpenOffice. still have no clue with this error :p

Comment: @tsurahman - Yes, I think CF9 uses POI (not OpenOffice) for the spreadsheet stuff.  Shot in the dark, but are you using any custom jars in either environment? Also, does this happen every time or only sometimes?

Comment: Hi Leigh, no third party add on or any custom jar, just different java version. also I tried on another server with CF9 dev win 7 starter fresh installation in it produce same error message

Comment: @tsurahman - Does using the same java version make any difference? Also, does the error occur anytime you use the spreadsheet functions on the IIS environments or just with this particular set of code?

Comment: @Leigh : I just tested it on 3 server. 2 fresh install (1 worked, 1 failed), and 1 IIS server (multi application) and failed on it.
also on failed server, it just simple statement `<cfset SpreadsheetObj = SpreadsheetNew()>`

Comment: @tsurahman - I am stumped on this one. Since they are clean installs, the only thing I could suggest would be to look for differences (jvm version, etcetera). See if there is a common pattern on the servers where it fails ..